# How to Overcome TypeError in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror

```
def myplo(data, PL):
    for name in PL:
        plt.plot(Points[0], c = Col[name], ls=":", marker= Shape[name], ms= MS[name], label = Players[0])
    plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
    plt.xticks(list(range(0,10)), Seasons, rotation= 'vertical')
    plt.show()
```

dictionaries and all other relevant functions been entered. But when I enter
myplot(Points)

following error occurs

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-215-e2827b75a02e> in <module>()
----> 1 myplo(Points)
TypeError: myplo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'PL'
```

Comment: `myplot` recive two parameters, `Points` is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace says what is going wrong.

When calling the function as `myplot(Points)` like you describe, you are only supplying one of the two required arguments.
Your function is defined as `def myplo(data, PL):` so the argument named `PL` is not receiving any data and it is required!